# How do I unlock the final missions in GTA: Vice City?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-vice-city

So I've never actually played Vice City through and I always seem to get stuck at around this particular point...

Due to the sandbox nature of the game, I thought I'd ask for a hand here and see if we can't figure out what I'm supposed to do next, so...

**What I've already done**

- Completed the Vercetti Estate missions (I have the $5000 passive income)
- Completed the Cortez missions (he's left)
- Completed the Love Fist missions that I have (last one was the bomb in the limo)
- Completed the Cuban/Hatian missions (killed the Cubans from the rooftop and bombed the Hatian facility)

There's nothing else on the map and I figure I probably need to purchase some extra properties to continue. I'll explore this idea going forward...

**So far I have purchased**

- Pole Position
- "Ice Cream" company
- Some safe houses dotted around

Clearly not the best way to spend my $$ and probably why I don't even have 100k yet, but nothing I can do about that now.

Does anyone have any suggestions what I can do next?

Comment: have you purchased the movie studio, if memory serve me right completing all it's missing gives you a passive income of up to $10,000 on collection, there's also some dock which has some missions as well that you can buy

Comment: @Memor-X can you remind me where the movie studio is? Got a feeling that'll get me to enough to buy Malibu pretty quickly

Comment: middle south of the map so it should be between the 2 main landmasses near the bottom of your map, i'm quite sure there was a mission where you had a gun fight in some house that was burning down on that same island bit is does have the main road going though it connecting the 2 land masses

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At this point there are multiple businesses which you can purchase. Each will unlock a short mission chain, minigame or activity which, when completed, earns you money per day.

Completing enough of these (which must include the printing press and The Malibu) will unlock the final missions.

Here's a list of the properties which make money:

- The boatyard- Costs $10k, produces $2k/day after completing a series
  of speedboat time trials.
- The ice cream factory- Costs $20k, produces $3k/day after earning enough money from the drug dealing minigame.
- The Pole Position club- Costs $30k, produces $4k/day after spending $300 in the back room.
- Kaufman Cabs- Costs 40k, produces 5k/day after completing the mission chain.
- Car showroom- Costs 50k, produces 6k/day after acquiring 4 lists of cars.
- Film studio- Costs 60k, produces 7k/day after completing the mission chain.
- Print works- Costs 70k, produces 8k/day after completing the mission chain and is **required** to unlock the final missions.
- The Malibu- Costs 120k, produces 10k/day after completing the mission chain and is also **required** for the final missions.

Comment: So far I've bought and completed the printing press and I've bought the doc (where you stole the boat for Diaz), but there doesn't seem to be any mission there... Unless it's triggered by getting in one of the boats... Otherwise it looks like just a save location

Comment: @Ortund The dock mission is started by entering either of the boats.

Comment: @Ortund I've added a list of assets to my post. I hope that helps.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the car showroom has a race mini game that allows you to earn 40k at 30k profit (if you win that is). Luckily, racing games are kind of my thing so I'm having tons of fun and earning tons of cash, too

Comment: @Ortund The showroom is awesome, especially when you finish the activity and it spawns some of the best cars in the game.

Comment: apparently the only business I have yet to buy is Kaufman... And I've completed the main storyline so far (just got Phil to the hospital)

Comment: @ortund Remember that they only count towards unlocking the final missions if they're earning money.

Comment: You don't have to buy The Malibu, at least not on PC. I just finished with these assets:
Boathouse
Kaufman cabs
Porn Studio
Ice Cream
Printworks
Strip Club

No other assets purchased, although obviously I got Diaz's place

Comment: Hey its not working, I have completed the Malibu and the print works asset missions and the missions haven't been unlocked just Phil which I guess isn't needed to unlock the final two missions

Answer (score -1):

guys after finishing love fist, mitch baker, cuban, haitian and the others, you should buy at least six properties and complete their missions.But you have to buy the malibu and the print works and finish their missions. Apart from that, buy and complete(my suggestion) kaufman cab, pole position club, boatyard and film studio.

Comment: You don't have to buy Malibu, at least not on PC

Answer (score -3):

Gta vice city hey you want last mision do Kens and mainly you dont buy film studio and kaufman cab. you buy only print works, the malibu. there is third mision in malibu is very hard. you had to complete cap ťhe collector nextyou wil
hear phone from ken you vercetti estate then you got last mision